# Overriding Integrated email "Send Email" on Opportunity Lightning Experience based on Opportunity field data

Tags: lightning

We want to move to lightning experience and are trying to recreate sf classic functionality where we used a custom button, a little javascript and a url hack to verify the opportunity stage = "stage 1" before allowing user to proceed to send an email linked to opportunity.

Any way to recreate this in Lightning?

Comment: A custom Lightning component.....JS buttons are not available in lightning at the moment

Comment: JS buttons will never make it to lightning .With new interfaces customers are asked to move either to a Visualforce based or a quick action or a component .

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the send email capability in lightning and customising will be lot of custom code and the out of box native UI of lightning gives you lot of  functionality .

Few releases back salesforce exposed object "EmailMessage" and now there is ability to write even triggers on these object before you send email .

Just tested a small POC to see if trigger will work on that

Here is the trigger approach for POC

```
trigger opportunityStageCheckOnEmail on EmailMessage (before insert,before update) {
 set<Id> setOppIds = new set<Id>();
 for(EmailMessage emailMessage : trigger.new){
  system.debug('***'+emailMessage.RelatedToId);
   setOppIds.add(emailMessage.RelatedToId);
 }
 map<Id,Opportunity> mapIdByOpportunity = new map<Id,Opportunity>([Select stageName from Opportunity where ID in :setOppIds]);
for(EmailMessage emailMessage : trigger.new){
    if(mapIdByOpportunity.get(emailMessage.RelatedToId).stageName == 'Closed Won'){
        emailMessage.addError('The opprtunity Stage has to be xyz');
     }
 }
}
```

[image]

Was able to get the opportunity Id in the relatedToId which means you can write a before insert and before update trigger and write the validation inside the trigger and throw the error message as per your business need .